# References about finite group theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, finite-groups

In your opinion which are the best books regarding the theory of finite groups? I think that a wonderful one is "Finite Group Theory - Michael Aschbacher".

Many thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to be Master in Rotman's great book then go for Robinson's group theory book.

Comment: Isaacs's *Finite Group Theory* is amazing, and a nice read.  Both Robinson's and Rotman's books cover infinite groups as well.  But all the suggestions so far are for the general theory of finite groups.  Do you want a specific branch of finite group theory, like representation theory, or cohomology? If so, you should state that in your question.

Comment: *The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher is not as comprehensive as Aschbacher's book and its first half is a good introduction for beginners, but its second half (Quadratic Action, The Embedding of $p$-Local Subgroups, Signalizer Functors and N-Groups) goes quite deep and shows also in some special case how to classify simple groups that are $N$-groups, i.e., groups of even order with all $2$-local subgroups solvable [usually $N$-group is the stronger condition that all $p$-local subgroups are solvable].